# Excel: Check if string contains one of multiple comma-separted keywords

Tags: microsoft-excel

| Keywords | String Samples | Expected Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| car, bike, train, dog, bird nest | c | FALSE |
|  | do | FALSE |
|  | dog | TRUE |
|  | train, car | TRUE |
|  | dogs | FALSE |
|  |  | FALSE |
|  | cars bikes | FALSE |
|  | bird | FALSE |
|  | bird nest | TRUE |
|  | Bird nest 2 | TRUE |
|  | bird nest2 | FALSE |

**Requirements**:

- The solution should not be limited to a specific Microsoft Excel Version.
- No helper columns should be used
- No macros should be used.

I tried solving it with SEARCH with SUMPRODUCT, but encountered the problem of false positives. To improve the formula my first challenge was to convert the comma-separated list of exclude words to an array which could be the basis for using SEARCH as array formula.

---

### Solutions tested in sample sheet:

- [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yu3g5SR9yfaIjWu7Du7VfaPdn93QVpReg4fM3JPWt8Y/edit?usp=sharing)
- [XLSX](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRfo-aOllA9IJoJbXpURAeMD6_0yWRQCcWlEaBG-Xa-qdwVbzzLfXqk_Vq4LMEDFbf-w-X1Fbqt8goK/pub?output=xlsx) (MS Excel)
- [ODS](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRfo-aOllA9IJoJbXpURAeMD6_0yWRQCcWlEaBG-Xa-qdwVbzzLfXqk_Vq4LMEDFbf-w-X1Fbqt8goK/pub?output=ods) (LibreOffice)

Comment: What have you tried to date.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: It's no homework, but how to convert the strings to an array and then search through the array with SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(things,B5)))

Comment: And those who down voted it, please let me know why.

Comment: You got downvoted because you did not explain in the post what you have tried and how it failed to do what you want.  Please [edit] the post to include the clarifications.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I tried to adjust it accordingly

Comment: The arbitrary limitations seem to indicate it IS a homework problem, or whatever version of that it is you're doing. If you can explain why these limitations are required, what you've tried, how it hasn't worked, we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(", "&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999))&", ",", "&$A$2&", ")))
```

`ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",",""))+1))`  Creates an array of numbers from 1 to the number of entities in the lookup string samples.  So for all but B5 it would be `{1}` for B5 it would be `{1;2}`

Then we subtract 1 to make it `0` based.  We then multiply that by `999` and get arrays like `{0;999}` then we add 1 back, `{1,1000}`.

This is the becomes the second criterion of the MID.  The third is `999`.

The first is a string where we put 999 spaces in place of any comma.  This allows for a large target of empty space.  We split somewhere in the middle of these large areas and then trim, returning an array of the search items, ie: `{"Train","Car"}`

We pass that to the first criterion of the SEARCH.  We append the `", "` to both the beginning and end of both criteria so we are looking for the complete word.

The AND will insure that all the words in the search criteria are found.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your answer and it works. I have issues though to follow and understand your explanation.

Comment: may I ask you one more question about your formula? In the string samples, I forgot to mention `bird nest 2` or `car 3`  which should also return TRUE. Could you please give me a hint how to adjust the formula to achieve this?

Comment: That is a different question and deserves its own post.  It is not an easy fix as one will need to have specific rules of what to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

After understanding the problem better myself, I had to add two more sample strings: 1. `Bird nest 2` which should result in `TRUE`. The search should not be case-sensitive and partly matching with keyword (if the separator is a space-character) would be enough. 2. `bird nest2` which result in `FALSE` because the 2 not separated by a space.

**The formula I am finally using for the problem:**

`{=AND(COUNT(SEARCH(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$2,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($ZA$1:INDEX($ZA:$ZA,LEN($A$2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$2,",",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999))&" ", B2&" ")))}`

see in  [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yu3g5SR9yfaIjWu7Du7VfaPdn93QVpReg4fM3JPWt8Y/edit?usp=sharing), [XLSX](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRfo-aOllA9IJoJbXpURAeMD6_0yWRQCcWlEaBG-Xa-qdwVbzzLfXqk_Vq4LMEDFbf-w-X1Fbqt8goK/pub?output=xlsx) or [ODS](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRfo-aOllA9IJoJbXpURAeMD6_0yWRQCcWlEaBG-Xa-qdwVbzzLfXqk_Vq4LMEDFbf-w-X1Fbqt8goK/pub?output=ods)

---

Thanks to Scott Craner for the core part `TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$2,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($ZA$1:INDEX($ZA:$ZA,LEN($A$2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$2,",",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999))&" "` which basically converts the comma-separated list of keywords to an array. In his post he converts the string samples to an array and I switched to convert the keywords to an array.

Using `SEARCH` as an array formula searches the sample string for each keyword in the array.

`COUNT` returns how many keywords where found in the string, and `AND` is returning `TRUE` if the number is different from 0.